# ssis 2010 zappysys more than 300 rows issue

Tags: ssis

I am using SSIS 2010 and using a test extension ZappySys connecting test JSON Source (rest API or File).

The issue I have is the total rows to scan 300 default. I have tried to override this, and it still returned 300 rows. I would like to use this extension more, but is there a way of getting more than 300 rows of data? Does anyone know how to by pass this?

There is this post on zappysys blog but does not state how to get more than 300 rows.

https://zappysys.com/blog/how-to-read-data-from-servicenow-rest-api-ssis/

Comment: Are you talking about the `MaxRows` property? I don't see anything in the JSON Source config dialog, or its Properties pane, that refer to "Total rows to scan = 300". How did you try to override this? 

If you are in fact talking about the `MaxRows` property, try setting it to 0, which means "no limit".

Comment: I think the "max rows to scan" property is used to help determine data types.

Comment: @digital.aaron I have tried this with no joy. Max rows is on 0. Under the columns setting - Total rows to scan or datatype guess is set to 300. I tried to set this to 0..it defaults to -1 with no joy. I have tried increasing this with no joy. still only brings down 300 rows please help.

Comment: @digital.aaron when you select filter , there is a scan limit, I have tried changing this too, and it defaults back to 300. please help

Comment: I just created a new test package that reads a JSON file with 320 records. I extracted all rows into a SQL Server table twice, once by setting `MaxRows` to 0, and the second time, setting it to 320. I then set it to 315, and got back only 315 rows. What is your destination connection type? When you say you have "no joy", i'm guessing you may be confusing the English idiom of having "no luck". So what, exactly is happening? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: I work for *ZappySys*.

Scan option affect only Metadata Guess in ZappySys. Based on your description Looks like your issue is not metadata guess but fetching more rows with pagination. Process of looping through ServiceNow data is described [here](https://hi.service-now.com/kb_view.do?sysparm_article=KB0727636)

For using pagination in ZappySys make sure you configure JSON source as per the article below

[Step-By-Step : Configure ServiceNow API Pagination](https://zappysys.com/blog/how-to-read-data-from-servicenow-rest-api-ssis/#Configure_JSON_Source_for_ServiceNow_API_Pagination)

Screenshot - Pagination Settings:
[image: Screenshot - Pagination Settings]

Here is an example of Pagination in ServiceNow. Let's say you fetching all rows for MyTable1. In such case you have to keep calling API like below until last page is reached. You detect last page by trapping WebException with StatusCode 404

```
/api/now/table/MyTable1?sysparm_limit=10&sysparm_offset=0
/api/now/table/MyTable1?sysparm_limit=10&sysparm_offset=10
/api/now/table/MyTable1?sysparm_limit=10&sysparm_offset=20
/api/now/table/MyTable1?sysparm_limit=10&sysparm_offset=30
/api/now/table/MyTable1?sysparm_limit=10&sysparm_offset=NNN ...Last page reached you get 404 error. Stop looping
```

ZappySys Pagination settings takes care of these for you automatically.